# Symfony 5 custom formType: set `data` option based on the value of 2 others options

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I am coding a reusable form type called `LdapAppGroupUserType` that take 2 options : `appDn`, `userName`.
The choices and the data options are calculated based on this 2 option values.

This form type is consummed as follow:

```
$form->add('groups', LdapAppGroupUserType::class, [
    'appDn' => $appDn,
    'userName' => $userName,
]);
```

Since this form must be reusable, I would like to move the code present in the `buildForm` method to `configureOptions` method.

This way, the form that will consume this field can be mapped more properly.

Instead of doing `$form->getData()->get('groups')['app_user_groups']`, I will be able to do: `$form->getData()->get('groups')`

My question is, how to pass from:

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Service\LdapClient;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class LdapAppGroupUserType extends AbstractType
{

    private LdapClient $ldapClient;

    public function __construct(LdapClient $ldapClient)
    {
        $this->ldapClient = $ldapClient;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $appDn = $options['appDn'];
        $userName = $options['userName'];
        $groups = $this->ldapClient->getGroupsForApp($appDn);
        $choices = array_combine($groups, $groups);
        $userGroups = $this->ldapClient->getUserGroupsForApp($userName, $appDn);
        dump($userName, $appDn, $userGroups, $choices);
        $builder
            ->add('app_user_groups', ChoiceType::class, [
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => true,
                'choices' => $choices,
                "data" => $userGroups,
                "empty_data" => $userGroups,
            ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'appDn' => null,
            'userName' => null,
        ]);
```

}

to something like that:

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Service\LdapClient;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class LdapAppGroupUserType extends AbstractType
{

    private LdapClient $ldapClient;

    public function __construct(LdapClient $ldapClient)
    {
        $this->ldapClient = $ldapClient;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'appDn' => null,
            'userName' => null,
            'expanded' => true,
            'multiple' => true,
        ]);

        $resolver->setNormalizer('data', function (OptionsResolver $resolver) {
            $appDn = $resolver->offsetGet('appDn');
            $userName = $resolver->offsetGet('userName');
            $userGroups = $this->ldapClient->getUserGroupsForApp($userName, $appDn);
            return $userGroups; //this has no effect! checkboxes are empty!
        });

        $resolver->setNormalizer('choices', function (OptionsResolver $resolver) {
            $appDn = $resolver->offsetGet('appDn');
            $groups = $this->ldapClient->getGroupsForApp($appDn);
            $choices = array_combine($groups, $groups);
            return $choices;
        });
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return ChoiceType::class;
    }
}
```

The `choices` option is well populated but I can't alter the `data` option this way.

*I am running symfony 5.4.*

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, but I had a similar problem today and solved it by modifying `configureOptions` like this, based on the `OptionsResolver` documentation here:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/options_resolver.html#default-values-that-depend-on-another-option

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'appDn' => null,
        'userName' => null,
        'expanded' => true,
        'multiple' => true,
    ]);
    
    $resolver->setDefault('data', function (Options $options) {
        $appDn = $options['appDn'];
        $userName = $options['userName'];
        $userGroups = $this->ldapClient->getUserGroupsForApp($userName, $appDn);
        return $userGroups;
    });     
    
    $resolver->setDefault('choices', function (Options $options) {
        $appDn = $options['appDn'];
        $groups = $this->ldapClient->getGroupsForApp($appDn);
        $choices = array_combine($groups, $groups);
        return $choices;
    });
}
```

And don't forget the use statement:

```
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\Options;
```